# Media Query for Large Desktop

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am working with a responsive website.

I want to design for all large desktop.

But I don't know the exact media query for large desktop.

Comment: https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/

Comment: This is a bad question to ask. Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What do you define as "Large Desktop"?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, they are the default bootstrap breakpoints.

```
/*==========  Mobile First Method  ==========*/

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {

}

/*==========  Non-Mobile First Method  ==========*/

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

}
```